# How can I start Apache on Arch Linux w/systemd using passphrase protected SSL keys?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, startup, ssl, apache-httpd

I'm relatively new to using Arch Linux and think I must be missing the obvious way to do this correctly, but –short of starting the daemon on my own– I can't figure out how to get passphrase protected SSL keys unlocked when starting the service normally. With unprotected keys or without the SSL configuration Apache starts normally using the systemd service. As soon as I try to use protected keys, I get something like this:

```
$ sudo systemctl start httpd
Job for httpd.service failed.

$ sudo systemctl status httpd
httpd.service - Apache Web Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2014-02-10 11:47:07 UTC; 13ms ago
  Process: 26035 ExecStop=/usr/bin/apachectl graceful-stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 26042 ExecStart=/usr/bin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 25500 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

systemd[1]: Starting Apache Web Server...
apachectl[26042]: Apache/2.2.26 mod_ssl/2.2.26 (Pass Phrase Dialog)
apachectl[26042]: Some of your private key files are encrypted for security reasons.
apachectl[26042]: In order to read them you have to provide the pass phrases.
apachectl[26042]: Server {name redacted}:443 (RSA)
apachectl[26042]: Enter pass phrase:Apache:mod_ssl:Error: Private key not found.
apachectl[26042]: **Stopped
systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Web Server.
systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
```

Is far as I can tell, Apache knows it needs to unlock my keys, but if systemd knows the passphrase prompt needs to be shown, any attempt to do so is not reaching my shell and silently failing.

What is the best practice way (or [Arch Way™](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/The_Arch_Way)) to start Apache and unlock protected SSL keys using systemd?

Comment: You typically strip the passphrase so the server can start w/o the challenge. https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RemoveSSLCertPassPhrase. I'm assuming you know this and want to keep it regardless, am I correct in my assumption?

Comment: @slm Yes, I am aware of this. I stripped the passphrase for testing this problem, but I need to configure it such that my intervention is required to unlock the cert.

Comment: That's what I figured but had to ask 8-)

Comment: Have you tried making use of the `SSLPassPhraseDialog` facility in Apache? http://serverfault.com/questions/160768/stop-apache-from-asking-for-ssl-password-each-restart

Comment: Also have a look here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=707917. Looks like Fedora ships a script that calls systemd for the passphrase: `SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/local/bin/httpd-ask-password`. Might be the way to do this in ArchLinux too.

Comment: This is not the way it is intended for, if yes please provide a reference. btw: for what reason?

Comment: @bersch - it's perfectly acceptable to have a passphrase here. It won't protect the setup, but it will protect the private 1/2 of the key pair from getting out.

Comment: @slm sorry I meant Caleb. My opinion is, that if the server have to be secure, i.e. accessible only by trusted admins, if it is not possible then forget thinking about security.

Comment: @bersch Your opinion an security practices does not invalidate my question about Arch's implementation of systemd/apache. You have a point about system security, but some certs do more than secure data over the wire, they also verify the identity of the provider. I want to be able to run an SSL service that is signed with my personal credentials on a box in a virtual machine in a shared environment where another admin could snapshot my machine and extract the file system. I realize it won't make the service and data the cert protects any more secure but it will prevent my ID from exploitation.

Comment: @bersch - I was replying to your concern though. What Caleb wants to do will protect the keys, so at the very least it would prevent anyone from gaining access to the keys who may have done something nefarious like captured all the encrypted traffic, and now wants to decrypt it. There are other reasons too, but his request is perfectly legit.

Comment: To whomever DV'ed this Q. It is a legitimate Q and does not warrant it. There are many technical reasons why someone would want to do this. Think out of the box on this! Do not assume that the OP is simply trying to naively secure his system by requiring a passphrase in a vain attempt to accomplish this!

Comment: @bersch And before you throw the book at me about virtual machines only being as secure as their host etc etc, I am not worried about the current admins or running environment so much as the backup system that ships snapshots offsite. I have the data in encrypted file systems so that is safe enough from, say, a tape getting into public hands but the root FS of the VM, per policy, needs to be a normal file system and I don't want to leave unlocked private keys that would work to serve things as being signed by me personally lying around on on a FS that might someday be other other admins.

Comment: Ok, agree, so the reason is that one cannot extract the keys from a backup or image. But beside of the reason, I am interested on the solution though, because any solution would be also vulnerable through other attacks. I am already delighted by this question +1.

Comment: @bersch These kinds of concerns would be something for answers to address, not the question.

Comment: @caleb - man ppl really have it in for this Q today. It was cycling to be closed as unclear too. I dropped a note in chat telling others to pls leave it open.

Comment: @slm Thanks. I'm open to suggestions on how to improve it. I'm a little surprised at the reaction myself. Maybe it's my dig at Arch-' "The Way"? I'm not a fanboy here, I'm just trying to use the tools the way they were intended to be used.

Comment: @Caleb - I'm surprised too. Q seems perfectly suited to this site. I think ppl are going with their knee jerk reaction rather then reading it. I'd hoped to cut that off by getting your clarification in the comments wrt to the stripped keys but it doesn't appear to be having the effect. I'm waiting for a Arch regular to jump in here, I don't use that distro so I can't offer more help, I believe Strugee and Jasonwryan are our 2 resident Archies/ers?. Jason most likely may not have seen it. If it gets worse I'll try and spin up a VM to see if I can't help though 8-)

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but the correct way to do this is to create `/etc/systemd/system/httpd.d/encryption.conf` (or whatever), then add `Requires=httpd-encryption.service` and `After=httpd-encryption.service`. then create `/etc/systemd/system/httpd-encryption.service` and have it be `Type=oneshot`. that should let you unlock your keys, but I'm not sure if stdin will be connected properly or not. if this works I'll write up an answer for you.

Comment: I've had this same problem, I think it should be filed as a bug.

Comment: @user3467349 Feature request maybe, but I don't see how it's a bug.

Comment: @Caleb well it's been awhile since I tried this (so feel free to correct me) - but last-time I tried a passworded ssl-key it was silently dropping the passphrase prompt as your question states, - that's an obvious bug (if it's not a feature it shouldn't be there at all).

Answer (score 2):

- Write a wrapper script around apache and put it to `ExecStart=` of the unit *(you may use drop-ins for that; no need to copy whole unit into `/etc`)*
- From the wrapper script, use `systemd-ask-password <PROMPT>`, read password from its stdout and feed it to apache in whatever way is required
- Don't forget to `exec` apache from the end of your script in order not to leave an extra bash process hanging around

This will make systemd query the password immediately (if you start apache using `systemctl`) or using one of so-called agents (there are default ones which ask passwords using wall or directly on the console). This is the best thing you can do to stay compliant.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the systemd way of doing it, but Apache makes this possible however it is started with the SSLPassPhraseDialog directive.  Basically, you create a small shell script in a file:

```
SSLPassPhraseDialog  /etc/domain.com_ssl_passphrase.sh
```

The contents of the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "passphrase"
```

Make sure the file is executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/domain.com_ssl_passphrase.sh
```

Now when you start Apache via systemd it will execute that script upon loading the SSL configuration for the site(s).

Comment: So your passphrase is saved as plaintext - what's the point then?